# Angular7 Template driven validation exports NgModel into a variable returns undefined

Tags: angular, angular7

I'm trying to establish a simple template driven form validation, with `#password="ngModel"` at the input file, when I read `password.length` i get `undefined` and i dont understand why

My angular form is:

```
<form #f="ngForm">
  <input class="form-control" placeholder='a' type="text" name="password" id="password" [(ngModel)]="renewPasswordData.password"
    #password="ngModel">

  {{password.length == null}} //<-- returns true
  <button [disabled]="password.length == 0" class="btn btn-success btn-block"> //<-- it not works
    {{"changePassword.change" | translate}}
  </button>
</form>
```

The ts file:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RenewPassword } from 'src/app/models/others/RenewPassword';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-change-password',
  templateUrl: './change-password.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./change-password.component.css']
})
export class ChangePasswordComponent implements OnInit {

  renewPasswordData = new RenewPassword("12", "");
  constructor(private router: Router) {
    console.log(this.renewPasswordData.password.length) //<-- return 2 (correct)
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

The model:

```
export class RenewPassword {
    constructor(
        public password: String,
        public rePassword: string
    ) {
    }
}
```

My ngModule Imports

```
imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
```

stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uzjqdq

Comment: try to use password.value.length

Comment: @Shohel Cannot read property 'length' of null

Comment: Angular safe navigation operator problem, could you share your full code to slackblitz

Comment: try using `renewPasswordData.password.length` it will work.

Comment: @Shohel its a big project with a lot of code, however, this component actually only have the form and code that I showed, the rest is commented

Comment: try to use renewPasswordData :  RenewPassword = new RenewPassword("12", ""); and renewPasswordData.password.length

Comment: @Shohel  renewPasswordData.password.length works, but i want to properties like password.errors and I can not in this way

Comment: @LaljiKanjareeya

Comment: @Shohel Same problem on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uzjqdq

Comment: where the place that you want to get password.error, will be into component or html template?

Comment: if you has [(ngModel)], use renewPasswordData.password, the use of @password="ngModel", serve to  take account of e.g. password.valid (if you use validators and so on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to remember, you have registered `password` as a `form control`. So your actual value is inside `password.value`, so that is what you need to check.

So check your condition on the button like:

```
<button [disabled]="password.value?.length === 0">
  send
</button>
```

**[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-poi3az?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

Comment: It works, but, where i registered password as a form control? i want to acces properties like password.errors and I can not in this way , the css class 'form-control' is for bootstrap(css)

Comment: You did it with when you inside form tags marked `name="password"` together with ngModel.

Comment: And you should be able to access `password.errors` just fine.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2gcpfx?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

if you need length for validation than please try below code, just set password minlength and maxlength

```
 <input type="text" #password="ngModel" name="password" [(ngModel)]="renewPasswordData.password" minlength="2" maxlength="5"/>
  <div *ngIf="password.invalid"> 
    Invalid Password
  </div>
```